# Random walk probability question: An urn contains $n$ white and $n$ black balls without replacement.

Tags: probability, random-walk

An urn contains $n$ white and $n$ black balls. We draw them one by one without replacement. We pay $£ 1$ for any black ball drawn but receive $£ 1$ for any white one. Denote by $X_i$ our money after the $i^{\text {th }}$ draw $\left(X_0=0\right)$. Let
$$
Y_i=\frac{X_i}{2 n-i} \quad(1 \leq i \leq 2 n-1), \quad \text { and } \quad Z_i=\frac{X_i^2-(2 n-i)}{(2 n-i)(2 n-i-1)} \quad(1 \leq i \leq 2 n-2) \text {. }
$$
(a) Show that both $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ are martingales.

Could I get some advice for trying to find the probability of X. I know the expectation of X is 1p - 1q where p+q =1 but I am struggling to quantify the probability of X as since the balls aren't being replaced. I think it might be a function along the lines of $\frac{k}{2n-i}$

Comment: If the answer below was helpful, see [How do I accept an answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have of course to specify a filtration on the set $\Omega$ of
all possible one-by-one extractions of the given white and black balls.
The number $n$ is fixed.
The chain of extraction has $N=2n$ places.
We extract the balls in order, and at the end of the time line, in $2n$ we have a chain $c=(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_N)$. The components are white (W) or black (B), but instead of $W$ and $B$ i prefer $1$ for white and $0$ for black.
We may also want to write $c$ as a word with $N$ letters, $c=c_1c_2\dotsc_N$.
Seen as an indicator function pattern, $c$ is determined by and determines the set of the $1$-places, let us denote it by $w(c)$ a set of $n$ places among
$1,2,\dots,N$. So $\Omega$, the modelling space, has $\binom Nn=\frac{N!}{n!n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ elements.

Which is the filtration?
The time line is $T=\{0,1,2,\dots ,N\}$.

At step $k$ in $T$ we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F_k$ on $\Omega$
covering all information available at time $k$. For $k=0$ we have the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.
At point one, we "see" $c_1$, so $F_1$ has two atoms, $A(0*)$ and $A(1*)$,
corresponding to all words that start with $0$, the first atom, and respectively all words that start with $1$, the second atom.
So $\mathcal F_1=\{\emptyset, 0*, 1*,\Omega=*=0*\sqcup1*\}$, it has four elements. At time $k$ we have $\mathcal F_k$, the $\sigma$-algebra with atoms $A(c'*)$. Here the atom $A(c'*)$ is the set of words starting with a word $c'=c_1c_2\dots c_k$ of length $k$, which does not contain more than $n$ zero entries, and no more than $n$ one entries. I will omit now the star in the notation, use only $A(c')$ intead.

---

Let us show now that $Y$ is a martingale. This means, that passing from step $k$ to step $k+1$ is a "fair" step. To see this, we may and do assume the information in $k$ is the one corresponding to an atom $A(c')$,
$c'=c_1c_2\dots c_k$. Let $w$ be the number of ones, $b$ the number of zeros in $c'$. Then on the atom $A(c')$ we have a constant value $Y(k) = \frac 1{N-k}X(k)=\frac{w-b}{N-k}$.

Constrained to $A(c')$, which is the probability for $c_{k+1}=1$, and which is the probability for $c_{k+1}=0$? There are $(n-w)$ white balls, and $(n-b)$ black balls still in the urn. In total, there are $(n-w)+(n-b)=2n-w-b=N-k$ balls still available.
The probability to get a further white ball is $(n-w)/(N-k)$.
The probability to get a further black ball is $(n-b)/(N-k)$.
So we compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Bbb E[\ Y(k+1)\ |\  A(c')\ ]
\\[2mm]
&\qquad=
\Bbb P [\ c_{k+1}=1\ |\  A(c')\ ]\cdot Y(k+1)(c'1)
\\
&\qquad+
\Bbb P [\ c_{k+1}=0\ |\  A(c')\ ]\cdot Y(k+1)(c'0)
\\[2mm]
&\qquad=
\frac{n-w}{N-k}\cdot\frac{X(k+1)(c'1)}{N-(k+1)}
+
\frac{n-b}{N-k}\cdot\frac{X(k+1)(c'0)}{N-(k+1)}
\\[2mm]
&\qquad=
\frac{n-w}{N-k}\cdot\frac{w+1-b}{N-(k+1)}
+
\frac{n-b}{N-k}\cdot\frac{w-1-b}{N-(k+1)}
\\[2mm]
&
\qquad=\frac 1{(N-k)(N-k-1)}
\underbrace{\Big((n-w)(w-b+1)+(n-b)(w-b-1)\Big)}
_{(n-w+n-b)(w-b)+(n-w)-(n-b)}
\\[2mm]
&
\qquad=\frac {(N-k)-1}{(N-k)(N-k-1)}(w-b)
=\frac{w-b}{N-k}
\\[2mm]
&
\qquad=\Bbb E[\ Y(k)\ | \ A(c')\ ]\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So $Y$ is a martingale.

A similar computation can be done for $Z$. Constrained to $A(c')$ we have
$Z(k)=\frac{X(k)^2 - (N-k)}{(N-k)(N-k-1)}
=\frac{(w-b)^2 - (N-k)}{(N-k)(N-k-1)}$. From $c'$ the world can see only $c_{k+1}=1$ or $c_{k+1}=0$ with the same probabilities as above, they determine $Z(k+1)$, and the win is from the point of view of the information in $A(c')$ equal to...
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Bbb E[\ Z(k+1)\ |\  A(c')\ ]
\\[2mm]
&\qquad=
\Bbb P [\ c_{k+1}=1\ |\  A(c')\ ]\cdot Z(k+1)(c'1)
\\
&\qquad+
\Bbb P [\ c_{k+1}=0\ |\  A(c')\ ]\cdot Z(k+1)(c'0)
\\[2mm]
&\qquad=
\frac{n-w}{N-k}\cdot\frac{X(k+1)(c'1)^2-(N-(k+1))}{(N-(k+1))(N-(k+1)-1)}
+
\frac{n-b}{N-k}\cdot\frac{X(k+1)(c'0)^2-(N-(k+1))}{(N-(k+1))(N-(k+1)-1)}
\\[2mm]
&\qquad=
\frac{n-w}{N-k}\cdot\frac{(w+1-b)^2-(N-k-1)}{(N-k-1)(N-k-2)}
+
\frac{n-b}{N-k}\cdot\frac{(w-1-b)^2-(N-k-1)}{(N-k-1)(N-k-2)}
\\[2mm]
&
\qquad=\frac {(n-w)(w-b\color{red}{+}1)^2+(n-b)(w-b\color{red}{-}1)^2-(n-w+n-b)(N-k-1)}
{(N-k)(N-k-1)(N-k-2)}
\\[2mm]
&
\qquad
=\frac 
{\scriptstyle(n-w+n-b)(w-b)^2 \color{red}{+ 2(n-w)(w-b)-2(n-w)(w-b)}+(n-w)+(n-b)
-(N-k)(N-k-1)}
{(N-k)(N-k-1)(N-k-2)}
\\[2mm]
&\qquad
=\frac 
{(N-k)(w-b)^2 \color{red}{- 2(w-b)^2} + (N-k)-(N-k)(N-k-1)}
{(N-k)(N-k-1)(N-k-2)}
\\[2mm]
&\qquad
=\frac 
{(N-k-2)(w-b)^2-(N-k)(N-k-2)}
{(N-k)(N-k-1)(N-k-2)}
\\[2mm]
&\qquad
=\frac 
{(w-b)^2-(N-k)}
{(N-k)(N-k-1)}
\\[2mm]
&
\qquad=\Bbb E[\ Z(k)\ | \ A(c')\ ]\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So $Z$ is a martingale, too.